# What to do if I answered a question incorrectly and the user self-deleted the question

Tags: discussion, deleted-questions

I was attempting to help a user and accidentally gave him a link that didn't address his question totally.

He was asking about what 'running `apt-get install <x-software>` does (how it knows where to look and how it knows what to do)' and I gave a link to a question answering a general 'how does `apt-get` work.

I was going to fix it, but the user self-deleted the question and I don't want them to go away not getting an answer I could provide.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Well, the short answer is... **Nothing.** Their post is gone; you can't do anything to it. Who knows if they'll ever come back?

Of course, if they had *other* posts on the site you might be able to leave a comment on one of them and help out that way. This could come across as somewhat stalkerish though, so don't over do it. And there's *still* the chance that the author has left and won't come back...

If they have a chat account, you could try inviting them into a room and letting them know that way. Unless, of course, they've completely left with no intention of ever returning.

In cases where the question *isn't* a duplicate, leaving an answer can prevent the question from being deleted by the author, *if* it gets an up-vote. This won't necessarily mean the author *sees* your corrections (if they've left, never to return, they won't), but it might at least help someone else. Of course, in the situation you're referencing, it *was* a duplicate.

FWIW, in this case the post you linked to appears to have [received an upvote](https://raspberrypi.stackexchange.com/users/6609/xxmbabanexx?tab=reputation) right about the time the post was deleted... So you may have been more helpful than you realized.